# I need to know how to do this, but it may be impossible

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

```
  import math
  import time
  import sys
  sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000000)
  def exit1():
    break
  def start():
    import time
    ans = input("Do you wish to start again? [y/n]\n")
    if ans == 'y' or ans == "yes" or ans == "":
      print(' \n' * 60)
    elif ans == 'n' or ans == "no":
      exit1()
    else:
      print("Invalid Input\n")
      time.sleep(3)
      start()

  def main():
    while True:
      print("Calculator:\n")
      aa = float(input("First number- "))
      ans = float(
          input(" do you want to:\n Add (1)\n Subtract (2)\n Multiply (3)\n Divide (4)\n Calculate an Exponent (5)\n "
                "Calculate Circumference of a circle(6)\n Calculate the Area of a Circle(7)\n Square Root(8)\n"))
      try:
        if ans != 1 and ans != 2 and ans != 3 and ans != 4 and ans != 5 and ans != 6 and ans != 7 and ans != 8:
          print("Invalid Operator Input")
          time.sleep(3)
          print(' \n' * 60)
          main()
        if ans == 6:
            print("If given diameter, Circumference is " + (aa * math.pi))
            start()
        if ans == 7:
            print("If given radius, Area is ")
            print(aa ** 2 * math.pi)
        if ans == 8:
            print("the square root of", + aa, "is", + (aa ** (1.0 / 2)))
            time.sleep(3)
            start()
        bb = float(input("Second Number- "))
        if ans == 1:
            pass
        elif ans == 2:
            print(aa - bb)
        elif ans == 3:
            print(aa * bb)
        elif ans == 4:
            print(aa / bb)
        elif ans == 5:
            print(aa ** bb)
        else:
            print("Invalid input")
        if aa == 9 and ans == 1 and bb == 10:
            print("21!")
        if aa != 9 and ans == 1 and bb != 10:
            print(aa + bb)
      except:
        print("Result Number Too High")

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

if you run my code you get the error: 'break' outside of loop. I don't know how or if there is even a way to do what I'm trying to do, which is stop everything but not kill the program. I want to display the arrow(s) again. I want to still be able to call main() still. I just want to be able to stop the while loop when call exit1().

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are calling your `exit1()` which is defined as:

```
def exit1():
    break
```

this is where your error is coming from, this will not work as that break is not in a loop, and you cannot `return break` either. You may just have to replace any calls of `exit1()` with `break`s.

You would not want to change this to a `quit()` or similar as your `exit1()`s are embedded in `start()` which is in the middle of your `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `start()` over an over at the end of `start()`, try instead just running a loop:

```
import time

def start():
    should_continue = True
    while should_continue:
        ans = input("Do you wish to start again? [y/n]\n")
        if ans == 'y' or ans == "yes" or ans == "":
            print(' \n' * 60)
        elif ans == 'n' or ans == "no":
            should_continue = False
        else:
            print("Invalid Input\n")
            time.sleep(3)
```

The code within the `while` block will run over and over until `should_continue` is made to be false (reading a new `ans` each loop, skipping whichever conditionals are not true every time) at which point it will not continue with the next iteration.

Alternatively, you could use `break` instead of creating an entire new variable (`break` can only be used directly within a loop):

```
def start():
    while True:
        ans = input("Do you wish to start again? [y/n]\n")
        if ans == 'y' or ans == "yes" or ans == "":
            print(' \n' * 60)
        elif ans == 'n' or ans == "no":
            break  # notice how this is inside a while loop - it will jump out of the while loop
        else:
            print("Invalid Input\n")
            time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: And same in main. He must not call main() from within main on invalid input but use next to start over with the while loop for example. (Thought it may work for a short lived manually driven program, it unnecesarry and unhelpful recursion wich consume ressources and will break the program at some level of recursion...)